# How to see how many repos created from my repo template (GitHub)

Tags: git, templates, github, git-fork

How can I see a list of all the child repos that have been created from my [template repo](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-template-repository) on GitHub?

GitHub displays how many forks were created from a given repo at the top of the WUI, next to the "stars" and "watches." And you can display a list of links to those users' forks under the "analytics" tab.

How can I get a similar list of all the repos that were created from my template repo on GitHub?

Comment: I wish there was an answer for this one, I Googled this question and found [this thread in GitHub Community](https://github.community/t/is-there-a-way-to-find-repositories-generated-from-my-template-repository/122838/2). Haven't seen any feedback on this thread, maybe you should vote up this thread, so it will get more attention

Comment: You can also request this feature through the feedback form https://support.github.com/contact/feedback

Answer (score 8):

Eureka! After reading this - [Search based on the contents of a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-based-on-the-contents-of-a-repository), the answer was clear! Search by README.md file content!

Use GitHub's search engine and provide a unique combination of words that appear in your README.md file. This is how I do it for my template - [unfor19/terraform-multienv](https://github.com/unfor19/terraform-multienv)

`in:readme sort:updated -user:unfor19 "tfmultienv"`
[github.com/search?q=in%3Areadme+sort%3Aupdated+-user%3Aunfor19+%22%60tfmultienv%60%22&type=repositories](https://github.com/search?q=in%3Areadme+sort%3Aupdated+-user%3Aunfor19+%22%60tfmultienv%60%22&type=repositories)

To get meaningful search results

- Sorting with `sort:updated`
- Filtering **out** my user name `-user:USERNAME` with [-QUALIFIER](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results).

Instead of hardcoding `USERNAME` you can use the keyword `@me`.

Comment: Of course this generally won't work, as nothing prevents users from nuking the template's README.md and adding their own content; and people usually do.

Comment: That's the best alternative I could find. Do you have a better alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Shell scripting and `gh` FTW:

```
#!/bin/bash

org_name="MYORGNAME"
repo_list=`gh repo list $org_name --limit 1000 | awk '{print $1}'`
template_repo=$1

if [ -z "$template_repo" ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <template_repo>"
  echo "  List repositories generated from a given template repository"
  echo "ABORTING!"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Searching for repositories generated from template: $template_repo"
for repo in $repo_list
do
  repo_info=`gh api repos/$repo`
  echo "$repo_info" | jq -r ".template_repository.full_name" | grep "$template_repo" 2>&1 > /dev/null
  if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
  then
    echo "repo_using_template: $repo"
  fi
done
```

Then, run `./find_repo_by_template.sh <template_repo>` to get a listing of repositories that use that template, AFTER setting the `org_name` variable.  My use case required searching within an organization.  If you have a different use case, you should be able to easily tweak my script to get the desired results.

Comment: So this doesn't work for searching all of GitHub.com (ie all users, not just a specific org)? I have no idea how to tweak this to search all users and all orgs. Can you please update the question with how to do that?

Comment: This worked perfect for my org!